# Which books give data on how humans grow physically from birth till death?

Tags: book-recommendation

I am searching books on how humans grow physically from the birth till death. I am not a biology student, and don't know any technical terms. I searched amazon but didn't find any such books. I need book to be precise. Even if the book is a textbook, it would be helpful.

If it is not possible to get all the data in one book, is there any other alternative reading to be made via multiple source reading.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Illustrated textbook of paediatrics' by Lissauer et al. (ISBN 9780723438717) contains a section about the average growth of children from birth up until puberty. After puberty humans don't grow anymore unless there is a medical condition. However it is important to understand that growth is influenced by many factor including ethnicity, sex, socioeconomic status and health and therefore precise numbers are hard to find.

For the most accurate information you should look for scientific publications for you specific population.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I seem to have been not precise in question, I intended to ask on how humans grow from the beginning and age till death. I am searching book(s) having these data, for knowing on what is to be made for living longer.....

Comment: ... These books might allow knowing on what chemicals (food) is to be had for increasing time of aging or to decrease the rate of growth, and to check on whether the ready-made exercise or food program are allowing to live longer or not. I have till now found Embryology (Developmental Biology) books, I still need to search adolescent developmental biology and might need to find books on how humans age physically. I will try reading journal articles, if I don't find books.